# Orange Pi Zero: Obtain IP without accessing Router Interface

Tags: ip, ip-address, raspbian, orange-pi

I have an Orange Pi Zero, which I have flashed DietPi on. It does not have HDMI, so I need to connect to it via Putty (or a similar program). The problem is that I cannot obtain the device's IP address, which seems to be a requirement in order for me to connect to it through programs like Putty.

The standard procedure for obtaining the Orange Pi's IP seems to be to log in to the admin Interface of the router, and to pull it out from there--but I am unable to do that because I am using my school's networks--and our IT Department has never had to perform anything like this, so the project has been put on hold.

Does anyone know of any other method to obtain the device IP? One in which I do not have to login to the router's admin interface (and preferably needs little to no intervention from the IT Department).

EDIT: A friend said it is possible to link the PC to the Orange Pi via Eternet cable and connect to it like that... I can't seem to find any information for doing so, does anyone know if this is possible? us

EDIT: I switched to DietPi--it had an easily accessible config file for preconfiguring the SSID and WiFi password. But I am having the same issue as before, finding out its IP address in order to connect to it.

Answer (score 3):

You could scan for devices on your network (if your school allows it)

Assuming you have a standard school network you could use following Linux command

```
nmap 10.32.1.*
```

To scan all the devices on the network and see if you can spot your Orange PI

See https://www.cyberciti.biz/security/nmap-command-examples-tutorials/

Comment: It unfortunately did not work, all ports were closed and nmap printed "Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details". I tried a few other commands from the article and Google searches, all ports were either closed or "filtered".

Comment: In doubt you can try to log in over SSH on the found host(s) with the default Orange Pi credentials. If you get in, and it's the only Orange Pi on the network, it should be your device.

Comment: You mean just by running `ssh orangepi` or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

modern versions of Raspian come with avahi/bonjour/zeroconf installed

Try using its machine name with ".local" appended, assuming my machine is called "billg-testbox", the following should work:

ssh pi@billg-testbox.local

The latest versions of Raspian also allow you to create a file named "ssh" in your boot directory to automatically enable SSH.

Comment: I should point out there is goofiness if the machine is attached via ethernet AND wireless. Best if there's only one interface

Comment: Very cool! But this assumes my device is already connected--is there a method to preconfigure that--enter WiFi SSID and password before booting?

Comment: Hmm, looked up the method to preconfigure the wifi Settings--then tried to connect via the pi's Name + .local appended to it... Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use serial port to talk with the orange pi.

When you plug your orange pi zero into your PC with USB cable you can enter the com number in putty and connect to your device via serial.

To get the com number you can use a simple serial terminals to get the list of available coms. Mine is com8 ([you can see the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnV8B.png) )

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert your sd card into your pc
2. Create an empty file named 'ssh' (not a folder)
3. Boot up your opi zero, wait 30 second, then connect to ssh